# Make a div index above another div and both are inside a wrapper

Tags: css, position, z-index

Ok so first it's my firstquestion here on Stackoverflow and the first question ever at all... 
I started learning web development two month ago and I learned HTML CSS and most of JS and some jQuery...
I never did any actual thing or experimented but now I'm trying to make my first project to start having practice..

So i've got this wrapper div and inside it I have two more divs, one is a kinda main content div and under it should be the other div which have a nice white img to blend with the overall website background. 
The problem is that I cant get the second div to be under the main div and inside the wrapper div. I've simlified it here in the code... Please let me know how to do it... 
Thanks and sorry if my English made you hit yourself in the face :)

The HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
  background-color:black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#first{
  width:250px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#second{
  width:350px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Edit:
I've made a Pen on CodePen to show you what I mean better... 
http://codepen.io/Avisaac/pen/DgIzi
This should be the resault only the gray div should be under the red div AND on the bottom of the red div, also i want the red div to be centered inside the wrapper. [plz notice that the wrapper should have the abillity to be centered also, as it is the main content area for my site which is centered.

I also attach a prtScr I took of my monitor to explain better:
the white square is the main content (meaning #first) the white gradient on the bottom is the second div (#second) which contains this gradient. the main content should be over the gradient so that the main content blend with the pattern background.. Hope I made it clearer
http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/2882/qg6j.jpg

Comment: By "under" do you mean overlayed or physically below? Two boxes on top of one another or one box made of two layers?

Comment: Height of #first and #second is 400px combined, but the .wrapper is only 350px. Is this desired? Could you provide a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I come up with a layout that looks almost "U"-shaped with two black upright columns on either side and a gray footer.

Comment: anyone can help? I've tried beeing more clear in the question.. the Answers i got did not help me so far...

Answer (score 0):

As @DevlshOne mentioned if your mean by **under** is **overlapped** try this:

```
.wrapper {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
 }

 #first{
     width:250px;
     height:300px;
     background-color: white;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0; left: 0;
 } 
 #second{
     width:350px;
     height:100px;
     background-color: gray;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0; left: 0;
 }
```

fiddle for this : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abforce/CyDY4/1/)

But if your mean is one in top and other in bottom try this;

```
.wrapper {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden /* or scroll or auto */
}
#first {
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 
#second{
    width:350px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

another fiddle for this one: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abforce/d7JxN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The heights and widths don't match. 
Try to add more to the wrapper's height, it's just 350px but if you add the two other div's height, it's 400px.